# Why is my predict function predicting the same probability for each row of my data?

Tags: r

```
labelled <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  veh_value exposure clm
  3.33      0.73     0
  0.99      0.82     1
  3.44      0.74     1
  2.50      0.68     0
  4.05      0.11     1
")
unlabelled <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  veh_value exposure 
  2.77      0.44     
  0.86      0.10     
  4.27      0.02     
  2.47      0.29     
  1.43      0.25     
")
##Preprocessing of both data sets 

labelled$veh_value =cut(labelled$veh_value,breaks=c(quantile(labelled$veh_value,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))))
labelled$exposure = cut(labelled$exposure,breaks=c(quantile(labelled$exposure,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))))
labelled$clm = as.factor(labelled$clm);

unlabelled$veh_value=cut(unlabelled$veh_value,breaks=c(quantile(unlabelled$veh_value,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))))
unlabelled$exposure =cut(unlabelled$exposure,breaks=c(quantile(unlabelled$exposure,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))))

##Training Model for labelled data 

library(e1071)
NBclassfierlabel=naiveBayes(clm~veh_value+exposure, laplace=1, data=labelled)

##Predicting posterior probabilities for the unlabelled data  

predict<- predict(NBclassfierlabel, newdata=unlabelled, type="raw")
```

I have included a sample of my labelled & unlabelled dataset. I have also included the preprocessing to run the naivebayes algorithm on my labelled dataset. I want to then predict the posterior probabilities of my unlabelled set by using `predict<- predict(NBclassfierlabel, newdata=unlabelled, type="raw")` When I run this code the same probability is returned for every row. Do you know why this is the case. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a small mistake while creating buckets for **veh_value** and **exposure** for unlabelled data. You are making the cuts in unlabelled data by taking `quantile` for unlabelled data itself, which is not the correct way of creating levels in unlabelled data. Whenever you want create buckets for unlabelled(test data), You should always keep the buckets(cuts labelled) from train data(in your case its labelled data). Ideally the cuts levels should match. The difference would be in the counts of rows under these levels between two datasets for each of the categories(levels). The problem is that even if someone mistakenly created levels erroneously, Naive Bayes doesn't fail but if you run a logistic regression(this would yield an error, this would yield mismatch of levels in your code).

Here is the modified code. Also while creating cuts, there are NAs coming on the lower side, So basically your cuts on left hand side were also missing(contains NA). So to avoid such cases, I have used Infs(-Inf, +Inf) at both the ends.

Here is your modified code with the given input:

```
p1 <- c(-Inf, c(quantile(labelled$veh_value,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))), Inf)

p2 <- c(-Inf, (quantile(labelled$exposure,probs=seq(0,1,by=0.25))), Inf)

labelled$veh_value =cut(labelled$veh_value,
                        breaks=p1)

labelled$exposure = cut(labelled$exposure,breaks=p2)
labelled$clm = as.factor(labelled$clm);

unlabelled$veh_value=cut(unlabelled$veh_value,breaks=p1)

unlabelled$exposure =cut(unlabelled$exposure,breaks=p2)

##Training Model for labelled data 
labelled
library(e1071)
NBclassfierlabel=naiveBayes(factor(clm)~veh_value+exposure, laplace=1, data=labelled)

##Predicting posterior probabilities for the unlabelled data  

str(labelled)

predict<- predict(NBclassfierlabel, newdata=unlabelled, type="raw")
```

**Output**:

```
                0            1
[1,] 0.7714285714 0.2285714286
[2,] 0.1741935484 0.8258064516
[3,] 0.2967032967 0.7032967033
[4,] 0.7714285714 0.2285714286
[5,] 0.7714285714 0.2285714286
R>
```

Comment: @Killian Gavin, was I able to help you out. Thanks